# Can I make SQL Server FORMAT deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, user-defined-functions

I want to make a UDF which returns an integer form of `YYYYMM` so that I can easily partition some things on month. I am trying to assign this function to the value of a `PERSISTED` computed column.

I currently have the following, which works fine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetYearMonth(@pDate DATETIME2)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fYear VARCHAR(4) = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(YEAR(@pDate) AS VARCHAR),4)
    DECLARE @fMonth VARCHAR(2) = RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(@pDate) AS VARCHAR),2)

    RETURN CAST(@fYear + @fMonth AS INT)
END
```

But I think it's cleaner to use `FORMAT` instead. I tried this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetYearMonth(@pDate DATETIME2)
RETURNS INT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fYear VARCHAR(4) = FORMAT(@pDate,'yyyy', 'en-us')
    DECLARE @fMonth VARCHAR(2) = FORMAT(@pDate,'MM', 'en-us')

    RETURN CAST(@fYear + @fMonth AS INT)
END
```

But this function is nondeterministic.
Is there a way to make `FORMAT` deterministic? Or is there a better way to do this, making the UDF deterministic?

Comment: Are you going to use a function for computed column?

Comment: @FLICKER yes, I am. A persisted one.

Comment: Please see my answer. I also don't know why you have used SCEHMEBINDING

Comment: @FLICKER `schemabinding` is required to have any chance of it being considered deterministic.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know that, anyway I think using convert will be deterministic too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting question so I did some digging and came up with nothing conclusive :)

Starting with [Deterministic and Nondeterministic Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091(v=sql.110).aspx)

which doesn't explicitly list `FORMAT` but states:

> All of the aggregate and string built-in functions are deterministic.

and links to [String Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984(v=sql.110).aspx)

Again, this page states

> All built-in string functions are deterministic. This means they return the same value any time they are called with a specific set of input values.

However, [the page on `FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx) is silent on the subject.

`FORMAT` uses the CLR which [doesn't preclude it from being deterministic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.isdeterministic(v=vs.110).aspx) but the doco is silent as to the actual implementation of `FORMAT`.

Finally, suspecting this is a bug in the doco (or the code) a [quick search of connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer) reveals nothing.

How about a test case? (Comments welcome on the validity of this code…)

```
CREATE FUNCTION WhatAmI(@Number INTEGER) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
BEGIN
RETURN FORMAT(@Number, 'd')
END
GO

SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('WhatAmI'),'IsDeterministic')

-----------
0

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Nup, that's nondeterministic.

So, an interesting exercise but nothing conclusive.

So what did we learn  (according to BOL)? If a built-in function is nondeterministic, there's no way of making it so. Some are both depending on the parameter types, and some are supposed to be but aren't.

Comment: Please [vote on fixing this bug](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/34621960-make-built-in-format-function-deterministic).

Answer (score 5):

I'm wondering why you are using a function. 
You can use a simple formula:

```
CONVERT(varchar(6), getdate(), 112)
```

Comment: because I didn't know I could do that

Comment: This comment gives me what I was looking for but doesn't specifically answer the question so I upvoted but didn't accept.

Comment: +1. Specifically, style 112 (ISO) is deterministic. Some styles are deterministic and some are not, according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#certain-datetime-conversions-are-nondeterministic).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft isn't very clear about the format function being able to be determinstic. I couldn't find any info on the subject in its documentation. Being a CLR function i guess the awnser is it is not possible.

An even more simple solution to get an integer formatted the way you want would be:

```
YEAR(@pDate) * 100 + MONTH(@pDate)
```

Comment: This comment gives me what I was looking for but doesn't specifically answer the question so I upvoted but didn't accept.